# ie8 appendchild not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I am developing a website that must run on IE8.

I need to create a bunch of dynamic paragraphs since I am pulling data from a server at runtime.

To do so I am using the following code:

```
var tempAbstract = layerItems[iter].abstract; // string
var text1 = document.createElement('p');      // paragraph element 
text1.textContent = tempAbstract;             // assigning string to paragraph
$(text1).css({top:  iter*25 + 30,  left: 200, position:'absolute'});  // positioning
$(text1).css('color', 'black');                                // make text color black
document.getElementById("listLayersWrapper").appendChild(text1);  // appending to div
```

My problem is that the text won't render.

When I count the paragraph `div`s before and after I add the element, the counter increments as you would expect it should yet the text does not render. Additionally, when I get call `position().left` and `position.top()` the element also has the right coordinates.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and have run out of options.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, why not do this with jQuery?

Comment: did not think about that... I just know this works on chrome for whatever reason but not ie8.... I'll give your way a try

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I replaced document.get... with $("#listLayersWrapper").append(text1);
and still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't appear to be with `appendChild`, but with `textContent`. According to [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), `textContent` is only available in IE9 and up. Older versions of IE do have a [non-standard `innerText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use to achieve the same thing. Here is how you can implement this.

**Example:**

```
var tempAbstract = layerItems[iter].abstract;
var text1 = document.createElement('p');
if(text1.textContent !== undefined)
{
    text1.textContent = tempAbstract;
}else{
    text1.innerText = tempAbstract;
}
$(text1).css({top:  iter*25 + 30,  left: 200, position:'absolute'});
$(text1).css('color', 'black');
document.getElementById("listLayersWrapper").appendChild(text1);
```

Alternatively, this could be implemented in jQuery.

**Example:**

```
$('<p></p>')
    .text(layerItems[iter].abstract)
    .css({
        top: iter*25 + 30,
        left: 200,
        position:'absolute',
        color: 'black'
    })
    .appendTo("#listLayersWrapper");
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually just solved this problem by using this: var text1 = $('<p />').text(tempName);     instead of what I had before. So it looks like what you said seems to work since I am not calling  textContent as well

Comment: ill test your code even though mine works and will mark it correct if it works.. thanks for the awesome answer regardless